# How to check a fulfilled promise from firebase function with Jest

Tags: javascript, firebase, jestjs

I am currently working on Jest to test if my doPasswordUpdate function works, but I don't really know how to write expect in jest because my signInwithEmailandPassword function returns a promise. I would like to expect a fulfilled promise after the test

```
import { doPasswordUpdate } from "../firebase/auth";
import { db } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { auth } from "../firebase/firebase";




test('Password is Updated', () => {
   auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test123@email.com", "123456").then(() => {
        doPasswordUpdate("234567");
      })
```

What I want is that I update the password from 123456 to 234567, and

> auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test123@email.com", "234567")

should return a fulfilled promise, which indicates that the function works.But I don't know how to operate promises with Jest, BTW the code below is not correct.

```
 expect(auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test123@email.com", "234567")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

> I have opened another question for the coding problem
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074695/strange-test-result-from-jest-with-firebase-signinwithemailandpassword-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: `resolves` is a property and not a function. Please ignore my comment.

You can use Jests's [`resolves`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves) property:

```
import { doPasswordUpdate } from "../firebase/auth";
import { db } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { auth } from "../firebase/firebase";




test('Password is Updated', () => {
   expect(auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test123@email.com", "123456")).resolves;
}
```

Comment: I get it!, so resolves only check for fulfilled promises? I look it up on Jest documentation and I thought it is more complicated than that. BTW I used expect (auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test123@email.com", "234567")).resolves; in the end without having bracket after resolves

Comment: Yes, `.resolves` checks if the promise was resolved. If it was rejected the test will fail. If you want to check the result, you can append a `toBe` behind the `resolves` (e.g. `.resolves().toBe('Hello user')`). If this answer solved your problem mark it as accepted with the big green checkmark so others will know you question is solved. Also, `resolves` is a function so you have to call it. See the link in my answer for more info.

Comment: So in my case, if I just want to see that the returned promise is fulfilled, I can just simply use .resolves and nothing else? So basically resolves means fulfilled?

Comment: Yes, basically. But make sure to call it as a function with paranthesis `resolves()` otherwise it won't work

Comment: That is strange, because when I tried it with the parenthesis, it gives me an error stating: TypeError: expect(...).resolves is not a function. But when I write it without the parentheses, the test is passed.

Comment: Oh yes sorry `resolves` is a property not a function. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I was messing around with the code, I realize there is something wrong, I replaced resolves with rejects, the test is still passed, but logically the test should fail, because 
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test123@email.com", "234567")
should return a fulfilled promise,  not a rejection.
And when I change the password inside of
expect (auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test123@email.com", "234567")).resolves; 
to "234767" the test gives a pass, but I updated the password to 234567, and using a wrong password should not return a fulfilled promise. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No idea. That's not supposed to happen, try opening an issue on the Github.